# Tidyeval problem in `case_when` when using function in right side formula

Tags: r, tidyeval

Consider the following structure:

```
tmp_data <- structure(
  list(
    currency = c("EUR", "USD"),
    funding = c(50, 700)),
 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

This I'm trying to convert to `EUR` across the board like so:

```
tmp_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    funding = dplyr::case_when(
      currency != "EUR" ~ yahoofinancer::currency_converter(
        from = currency, to = "EUR",
        start = lubridate::today())$adj_close * funding,
      TRUE ~ funding))
```

While this works when explicitly changing `from = currency` to `from = "USD"`, I cannot get this to work using the `currency` variable na matter what `quo`, `enquo`, `{{` or other `tidyeval` constructs come to mind (and `google`).

The error mostly remains

```
Failed to evaluate the right-hand side of formula 1.
```

How do I get this to work? Thanks for any pointers...

Comment: that's a gotcha: rewrite from `tmp_data %>% ...` to `tmp_data %>% rowwise() %>% ...` ;-)
(`rowwise` being provided by {dplyr})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `rowwise()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(yahoofinancer)

temp_data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(funding = case_when(
    currency != "EUR" ~ pull(currency_converter(from = currency, to = "EUR", start = today()), adj_close) * funding, 
    .default = funding
  ))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Rowwise: 
  currency funding
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 EUR          50 
2 USD         645.
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. Just had figured out that the issue is that `currency_converter` is not vectorized ...  but why the `pull` bit?

Comment: @balin `pull()` is tidyverses approach to $adj_close

Comment: @Chamkrai: interesting. `magrittr::extract*` has been my goto function for that...

Answer (score 2):

The RHS of `case_when()` should be vectorised - i.e. your function should return a vector the same length as the number of rows, it's not run per-row, it's run once then the relevant results are extracted.

Yoiu can amend that by either forcing `rowwise()` evaluation or by vectorising your function using something like the `map` family:

```
tmp_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    funding = dplyr::case_when(
      currency != "EUR" ~ map_dbl(`currency`, ~ yahoofinancer::currency_converter(
        from = ., to = "EUR",
        start = lubridate::today())$adj_close) * funding,
      TRUE ~ funding))
```